# DBeaver - Connections closed by foreign host

Tags: mysql, database, connection, dbeaver

I am trying to connect with mySQL, and I keep getting the following error:

> Can't initialize tunnel   Cannot establish tunnel
>       connection is closed by foreign host
>       connection is closed by foreign host

I am not sure how to proceed. I have entered the following details in the mySQL connection settings : 
host: localhost
Post: 3306
Ueseranme: root
password: mypassword

Any advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a local database on your machine, make sure to uncheck the "Use SSH Tunnel" checkbox (it's on the "Network" page of the "Create new connection" wizard).

[image]

If you're using a remote database (namely a one that is hosted on another server) that requires an SSH tunnel connection, check the "Use SSH Tunnel" checkbox and fill in the relevant information in the "Network" page. Notice that in most cases it will require you to have an appropriate private key, in that case you'll have to switch the "Authentication Method" from "Password" to "Public Key".

[image]